# Someone please explain what is the use of now and how it is working here

Tags: vue.js

I am new to Vue.js and have some understanding how watch works here. Can someone please explain how **now** function is working here. Thanks in Advance. your help is much appreciated.

```
watch:{
      now: function(newNow){
           this.someTimeInSec = // methodcall to return the time in sec
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when we want to react to any data changes, in this case "now", we can define methods against that data variable in the watch property.

Two values *newValue*, *oldValue* will be passed to this function and you can update other properties/UI accordingly.

This is well documented in the o[fficial docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers)

Comment: but we don't have any data named "now".